# JPEG RGB to DICOM Grayscale Standard

Tags: c#, jpeg, rgb, dicom

I have a jpeg file that was converted from a DICOM image, when I convert the JPEG back to DICOM, the new image does not have pixel data becasue all grayscale data are stored in a single byte channel.  I need each pixel to store its data in a format that I can use to change the window width and center using c#.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that window level, after going from DICOM -> JPEG -> DICOM is not going to be diagnostic-grade. You will use fidelity going from DICOM -> JPEG. JPEG is a lossy format, so, even if you have the full bit-depth of the DICOM image (let's say 12 bit -> 12 bit), there might still be artifacts in the image or other JPEG-specific compression side effects.

That said, the pixel data is still there, it's just stored a bit differently than the original DICOM. You should still be able to use the same algorithm you would for regular DICOM (there are a lot of references online).

Comment: Thanks Anatoly, the pixel data is stored in a single channel that is why my window level does not work.